# How do I show or hide div, based on position of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery that slides a div horizontally:

```
$('.nextcol').click(function() {
    $('.innerslide').animate({'left': '-=711px'}, 1000);
});

$('.prevcol').click(function() {
    $('.innerslide').animate({'left': '+=711px'}, 1000);
});
```

What I want to happen is this... if the *div.innerslide* has a position that is **left: 0px** then I want to hide *div.backarrow*. If the position is not **left: 0px**, then it shows it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT (added HTML Markup)**

```
<div class="backarrow prevcol">

<div id="mainleft" class="overflowhidden">
        <div class="innerslide">
            <div class="col">my content including <a href="#" class="nextcol">next</a></div>
            <div class="col">my content including <a href="#" class="nextcol">next</a></div>
            <div class="col">my content including <a href="#" class="nextcol">next</a></div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: are you looking to have your script check the position WHILE the div is animating, or before/after?

Comment: If you post your HTML and the full jQuery (if there is more) I can help you further. I think I know what you're trying to do, but I can't give you a more detailed solution unless I can see the rest of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($('.innerslide').css("left") == 0) {
   $('div.backarrow').hide(); 
} else {
   $('div.backarrow').show();
}
```

**Fix for Double-Click Issue:**
From what you described in your comment about the issue when the visitor double-clicks, it sounds like the double-click is causing two of the animation events to fire. To keep this from happening, you can either disable the click handler while the animation is running and re-enable it once it is finished, or you can try to write a new thread to continually check the element's position. One of these solutions is not a good idea - I'll let you figure out which one :) - but the other actually has a very simple solution that requires little change to your existing code (and may actually reduce your overhead by a teeny weeny amount):

```
$('.nextcol').on("click.next", function() {
    $('.innerslide').animate({'left': '-=711px'}, 1000, showHideBack());
    $(this).off("click.next");
});

$('.prevcol').on("click.prev", function() {
    $('.innerslide').animate({'left': '+=711px'}, 1000, showHideForward());
    $(this).off("click.prev");
});
```

Then add this this line to `showHideBack()` (and a complementary one to `showHideForward()` if you are using that):

```
$('.nextcol').on("click.next".....
```

I suggest that you write a function to set each click handler and another to remove each one. This will make your live very easy and the whole solution should reduce overhead by removing unnecessary click handlers while the animation is running.

Note: the `animation` method often calls its callback before the animation finishes. As such, you may wish to use a `delay` before calling the `showHide...` method(s).

Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck! :)

**UPDATE:**

Here is the [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/fSVuu/17/) of the fiddle you gave me with all bugs ironed out. It looks like I misunderstood part of your goal in my original solution, but I straightened it out here. I have also included the updated jQuery, here:

```
var speed = 1000;
var back = $("div.backarrow");
var next = $(".nextcol");
var prev = $(".prevcol");
var inner = $(".innerslide");

function clickNext(index) {
    next.off("click.next");
    inner.animate({
        'left': '-=711px'
    }, speed, function() {
        back.show(); //this line will only be hit if there is a previous column to show
            next.delay(speed).on("click.next", function() {
                clickNext();
            });
    });
}

function clickPrev() {
    prev.off("click.prev");
    inner.animate({
        'left': '+=711px'
    }, speed, function() {
        if (inner.css("left") == "0px") {
            back.delay(speed).hide();
            prev.delay(speed).on("click.prev", function() {
                clickPrev();
            });
        } else {
            back.delay(speed).show();
            prev.delay(speed).on("click.prev", function() {
                clickPrev();
            });
        }
    });
}

next.on("click.next", function() {
    clickNext();
});

prev.on("click.prev", function() {
    clickPrev();
});​
```

I was going to also include a condition to check if you were viewing the last column, but, as I don't know what your final implementation will be, I didn't know if it would be applicable. As always, let me know if you need help or clarification on any of this. :)

Comment: It's not quite working as expected. The .nextcol and .prevcol stop working and the back arrow doesn't disappear when back to zero.

I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fSVuu/1/) to show you where I am and for you to see all code and it (not) working.

Thanks ever so much for your help so far!!

Comment: do you have a link to it, as my link is only showing my revision?

Comment: got it!! [http://jsfiddle.net/fSVuu/15/](http://jsfiddle.net/fSVuu/15/) Works perfectly! Can't thank you enough for all the time you put into helping me!

Comment: Not a problem -  if you need anymore help,  don't hesitate to comment.  Good luck!  =)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [`step`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) option — a callback function that is fired at each step of the animation:

```
$('.prevcol').click(function() {
    $('.innerslide').animate({ left: '+=711px' },
           {
               duration: 1000,
               step: function(now, fx) {
                      if (now === 0 ) {
                           $('div.backarrow').hide(); 
                      } else {
                           $('div.backarrow').show();
                      }
              }
    });
});
```

More examples of usage in this article [The jQuery animate() step callback function](http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/03/01/the-jquery-animate-step-callback-function/)

Comment: I like this solution, and I would have offered a similar one, however when I asked when he was looking to check (before, during or after the animation), he replied "before ideally". I think this is a good solution, but I don't think it's exactly what he was looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I would agree it might not be the best solution to his spec

Comment: thanks both of you for your help... this code works well, but the problem I have is that if the user 'double clicks' the back arrow (.prevcol) to take it back to 0px, then it skips past left: 0px. SO ideally it needs to behave more like this perhaps?

If when clicking on .prevcol and the left position is -711px then it hides the back arrow immediately to prevent a double click taking .innerslide to +711px.

Comment: Adam, I added a fix for this to my solution. As much as I like chridam's solution, I don't think it will help for your issue (especially in slower and older browsers), as you will still have the issue of two animations running at once (that is the cause of your issue)